# Is there something like bitcore for Ethereum?

Tags: bitcoin, javascript, python, library

In Bitcoin there is a library named [Bitcore](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore).  It helps abstract away a number of details, including using direct RPC commands.  Is there something like Bitcore for Ethereum?  Or do I need to use JSON-RPC?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Could you explain which bitcore functionality are you missing? In addition, try to ask one question per thread. Create a new question for the open source blockchain explorer.

Comment: I'm editing the question and please create a new question for the explorer as suggested by 5chdn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are libraries you may find helpful:

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js - for DApp development so you don't have to use JSON-RPC directly

https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumjs-lib - Bitcore-like Javascript library for Ethereum

https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum - Bitcore-like Python library for Ethereum

Comment: Do these allow you to scan the full blockchain?

Comment: @Shamoon They can help you get data from the full blockchain if you use them on a synced Ethereum node.